# Passing object to partial() view helper in ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, partials

I'm trying to pass an `object` to the `partial()` view helper. While working with normal variables workes fine, I'm not able to pass object to this function.

For example, this workes fine when using `$this->test` in partial:

```
$this->partial("module/folder/partial.phtml", array(
    "test" => "foo",
));
```

But doing the same with an `object` will result in nothing in partial:

```
$this->partial("module/folder/partial.phtml", array(
    "test" => $this,
));
```

I've even tried using `setObjectKey`, what didn't woked too:

```
$this->partial()->setObjectKey("test");
$this->partial("module/folder/partial.phtml", $this);
```

Is there a way to pass an `object` to an single partial in ZF2?

I want to do this, because my view actually contains many informations the partial needs. I could add them all *line-by-line* to the partial, but that would just be overhead ...

Comment: The second argument of the partial viewhelper should just be an array and you should be able to pass objects or whatever you want to the partial. Within the partial you should use the key as a variable: `$test` to get the object within the partial. Maybe you could add what your result is of what you tried and how you call the variable within your partial.

Comment: @Kwido As said in the question, that I used `$this->test`, but I also tried just `$test`. But both don't works. The result is, that you can't access any property of the original object in the partial. 

I've made some more debugging, `$this` of the parent view and `$test` of the partial are both class type `Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer`, what is correct in general. But accessing a property in the partial with `$test->foo` don't return anything, while using the same in parent with `$this->foo` return the expected value ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass the parent `Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer` to your partial it will overwrite/replaces the `$test` variable with the `Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer` of your partial, like it is re-using the class. So resulting in a object that is empty as your partial `PhpRenderer` has no other variables included.

If you want the variables from the parent `PhpRender` use the following:

```php
$this->partial('folder/partial', ['vars' => $this->vars()->getArrayCopy()]);
// Or so, so you don't need to store the originals within the vars key
$this->partial('folder/partial', $this->vars()->getArrayCopy());
```

Now within your partial.phtml:

```
$this->vars['foo']
```

To confirm this, let your controller return some variable `['foo' => 'bar']` or setup a `ViewModel` with some test variables. Now setup your partial:

```
$this->partial('folder/partial.phtml', ['test' => 'abc' 'render' => $this].
```

And when you debug or `var_dump()` your PhpRenders variable you'll see that `$render` containts the variable `$test` with a value of abc and not the key 'foo' with 'bar' as its value. So it looks like the PhpRenderer is being reused so passing the parent `PhpRenderer` is not possible.